# Multiple Linear Regression from scratch?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, multiple-regression, multivariate-analysis

I am using multiple linear regression for my  python project to predict prices of used cars. I want to do this from scratch and not rely on any libraries to do this for me. I cannot find any material that teaches multiple linear from scratch with a worked example using a data set to formulate the models/predict the values of the dependant variables.

Can someone please advice me on how the maths with a worked example on how i can do this with a given data set. Every tutorial online uses a statistical package to do so, i need to see the step by step maths behind it.

Thank you very much

Comment: Just google 'OLS in python'. You need to be comfortable with matrix notation to understand what you will find, however.

Comment: They are packages and libraries, i need to see the logic and steps behind how the results were derived